# how to extend AbstractUser model in a different app in django

Tags: serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a class `User` that inherits from `AbstractUser` in a different django app called `accounts`. I have then referenced it in the `Employee` class in `user` Field. The problem is I can't view the full names of the user in API view in django_rest.

```
class User(AbstractUser):

   def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.last_name.upper(), self.first_name)
        return full_name.strip()



class Employee(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tax_id_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, null=True, verbose_name='Tax ID')
    account_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, null=True, verbose_name='Account Number')
    joining_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name="Joining Date")
    designation = models.ForeignKey(Group,related_name='designation',blank=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Group,related_name='department',blank=True)
```

**Employee serializer is as follows**

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # TODO: Define serializer fields here
    user = UserSerializer
    # designation = GroupListSerializer()
    # department = GroupListSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['user','tax_id_number','account_number','joining_date','designation','department']



    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        employee = Employee.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for user in user_data:
            user, created = User.objects.get()
            employee.user.add(user)
        return employee
```

Comment: Pl. post the serializers that you have written as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **get_full_name** as one of the fields in the model serializer then the problem is that it is not a property.

You need to use the **@property** decorator for the model serializer to be able to access it.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    @property 
    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.last_name.upper(), self.first_name)
        return full_name.strip()
```

The difference is when you use the **@property** decorator the python object allows the defined method to be accessed like a field. DRF's serializers assumes that the names being listed down in the `fields` tuple are attributes

Example:

```
>>> class A:
...  @property
...  def x(self):
...   return 2
...  def y(self):
...   return 3
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x
2
>>> a.y
<bound method A.y of <__main__.A instance at 0x10556d368>>
>>>
```

One final piece of advice would be not to use `get_full_name` as the name for the property. Even though properties are methods should not have a verb as a name. You can simply use `full_name` as the property name.

Comment: I didn't understand the question here.